# Connect JConsole to another user's process

Tags: java, windows, jvm, jconsole, jrmp

I've got a Win64 C++ program that hosts a JVM. When executing normally, I can connect to it from JConsole and see the stats. The process appears in the list of local processes.

When the same program is running as another user (from a scheduled job with saved credentials), the process is not in the list. I've got admin rights on the machine, not sure if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the PID of the process in Task Manager, then run

```
"PATH_TO_JDK_BIN\jconsole" PID
```

Answer (score 1):

Java creates a `hsperfdata_xxx` directory in the TEMP directory. In it information of the processes running in the jvm are saved. Only when the jvm running jconsole uses the same directory as the java application you want to inspect they can *see* each other.
I assume the other user has a other TEMP directory and that's why your jconsole cannot see the other application.
I propose you set the same TEMP directory for both users.
I've had this problem with multiple java installations for one user.